# Can't properly set the_title add_filter to show short_URL

Tags: functions, filters, hooks, get-the-title

I am trying to show Bitly's Post short URLs for my blog posts but something seems off as when I am using this code, I see the output all over the page for menu items etc...

Additionally, the URL doesn't seem to be outputted correctly. After many attempts, I am trying to use this:

```
function shorturl_after_title( $title ) {
    if ( function_exists('wp_get_shortlink') && is_single() && 'post' == get_post_type() ) {

            $aftertitle = "<br><span class='post-shortlink'>رابط مختصر:
<input type='text' value='<?php echo wp_get_shortlink(get_the_ID()); ?>' onclick='this.focus(); this.select();' />
</span>";           
            $custom_title = $title . $aftertitle;
            return $custom_title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'shorturl_after_title' );
```

Can you please help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's a second argument passed to `the_title` filter, which is the ID of the post the filter is currently operating on. This is important, as you've discovered, because the filter runs any time a title is output- in a menu item, widget, any secondary query, etc., so you need to check if that post ID matches the ID of the post you're currently viewing.

Your other problem is a syntax issue where you set `$aftertitle`. You've got php open/close braces and an `echo` inside there where you should be using string concatenation, like the way you join `$title . $aftertitle` on the next line. Anyway, we can do that a bit differently.

So here's a new version of your function. We can combine the single and post type checks into one, and I think it's safe to assume that `wp_get_shortlink` exists in this context. We then use php `sprintf` to generate the string, this is just a personal preference.

```
function shorturl_after_title( $title, $post_id ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) && $post_id == get_queried_object_id() ) {
        $text = "%s<br><span class='post-shortlink'>رابط مختصر:<input type='text' value='%s' onclick='this.focus(); this.select();' /></span>";           
        $title = sprintf( $text, $title, wp_get_shortlink( $post_id ) );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'shorturl_after_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks! I noticed a few things off and I am wondering if it's just on my end. The short URLs are showing both before the title and after it. It also seems there is a rouge '> being added after the title. Is there perhaps a better way to show something next to the title or below it that doesn't inherent the H and A tags from the title?